# What exactly does `XMLStreamReader.getEncoding()` do?

Tags: java, xml, stax

`XMLStreamReader`'s `getCharacterEncodingScheme()` returns the `encoding` attribute of the `<?xml encoding="utf-8">` line. But if `getCharacterEncodingScheme()` is enough, then why is there `getEncoding()?` **What exactly does `XMLStreamReader.getEncoding()` do?**

The javadocs say hardly anything.

`javax\xml\stream\XMLStreamReader.java`

```java
  /**
   * Return input encoding if known or null if unknown.
   * @return the encoding of this instance or null
   */
  public String getEncoding();
```

What's the purpose of `getEncoding()`, how does it differ from `getCharacterEncodingScheme()`, and how is the return value of `getEncoding()` determined with respects to the input XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create an `XMLStreamReader`.  One of those ways takes the name of the encoding as a parameter ... rather than taking it from the input XML's explicit `encoding` attribute.

So the purpose of `getEncoding()` is to return the actual encoding being used (if it is known) ... as distinct from the encoding that was declared in the `<xml>` element.

Note: it is possible that the `XMLStreamReader` doesn't know what the encoding used when reading the XML.  For example, when a `XMLStreamReader` is instantiated from a `Reader`, the decoder that the reader uses cannot be determined via the `Reader` API.